# Missing array_hash() function. Can not create a hash of an array

Tags: php, hash

**Intro**:

I need a function that can take an array and return a hash of it.

This should similar to [spl_object_hash()](http://php.net/spl_object_hash), except that it returns a hash for given array.

So, far I've tried

```
function array_hash(array $array) {

   return spl_object_hash((object) $array); 
}
```

**The problems**

1) This algorithm isn't efficient by itself. For example, what if I pass something like this:

```
  $array = array(
     'foo' => 'bar',
     'bool' => false,
     'junk' => array(
         'junk1' => array('foo' => array('__test__'))
      )
  )
```

It won't cast nested arrays to objects.

2) Another major problem is that, `spl_object_hash()` returns a different hash for the same object on each new HTTP request.

**The question**

Again: I need a persistent hash for an array. Unlike `spl_object_hash()`, the will  be persistent on each HTTP request. **How can I do this correctly?**

Comment: You could `serialize()` it and then `hash()` it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about serializing the array first?

```
md5(serialize($array));
```

Comment: Thanks! `serialize()` is good for objects as well as arrays. `json_decode()` will be better here as it intends to be used with arrays only. So I've found this to be more appropriate `sha1(json_encode($array))`

Comment: Glad you got creative with it!

Answer (score 1):

The above answer by Martin works fine but what I do:

```
function array_signature($arr, $sort=true)
{
    // Sorting helps generating a similar fingerprint for similar arrays
    if($sort) {
        array_multisort($arr);
    }

    // MD5 seems to be the fastest hashing function -- we don't care about collision for this
    // JSON seems faster than serialize()
    return md5(json_encode($arr));
}
```

Calling  `array_multisort()` first ensures that, for associative arrays, the same signature is returned for:

- `['a'=>1, 'b'=>2]`
- `['b'=>2, 'a'=>1]`

Benchmarks seem to agree: `md5()` is the fastest hashing function in PHP. It has a lot of potential security issues so should not be used for hashing passwords, but for an array signature this should not be an issue.

Similarly, `json_encode()` is the fastest encoding algorithm in PHP (faster than `serialize()`)